# JSoup not connecting to provided url

Tags: java, android, http, jsoup

I'm trying to parse some html from my companys public webspace.
For this i got the following code:

```
try {
                String url = "http://www.mycompany.com/company/new/";
                doc = Jsoup.connect(url).timeout(10 * 1000).get();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                exception = Log.getStackTraceString(e);
                Log.wtf("Error", e);
            }
```

This gives me the following error:

```
03-26 12:03:23.292  22026-22044/de.company A/Error﹕ failed to connect to www.mycompany.com/91.102.115.250 (port 80) after 10000ms
    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to www.mycompany.com/91.102.115.250 (port 80) after 10000ms
```

If I only provide "http://www.mycompany.com" it will successfully connect.

Where does the IP come from? How does this happen?!?

Thanks for any help on this :)

Comment: Try both urls in a browser and you will see.

Comment: @greenapps My provided URL works, the url from the error does not (timeout).

Comment: Please try both in a browser. And tell the results. Or were that the results from pesting in a browser? Please be clear. What does the browser display?

Comment: @greenapps that was the result from the browser. My provided URL is a copy-paste from the browser. It works and points directly to where it should. The url from the logcat (with the ip in it) does not work. The browser times out. I don't even understand, where the ip in the url comes from.

Comment: If the browser times out there will be a 404 File Not Found. So your url is invalid. If your browser cannot even find the page then why do you wonder jsoup isn't able too?

Comment: @greenapps please look at the code. I am givin a VALID URL which definitely works and Jsoup tries to connect to an INVALID URL. I do not know why JSoup adds an IP-Adress to the URL. That's the Problem...

Comment: No it is NOT a valid url as your browser can´t find the page either. JSOUP does not add an ip to the url. It only prints the ip in the errorlog.

Comment: @greenapps Well if my URL isn't valid, why does my browser find it then? It works! only when JSoup tries to connect to it, i find the IP in the error log.
If i replace my URL with something like "http://google.com" it seems to work again

Comment: You should try in your browser not the one in the error but the one you use for jsoup. `http://www.mycompany.com/company/new/`. This will give a 404.

Comment: @greenapps yes, this is the working url. it works. jesus...
fyi: this is not the real url...

Comment: No. of course i know that it is fake. But you posted the ip of your server. So try both in a browser `http://91.102.115.250` and `http://91.102.115.250/company/new/`. The latter one does not work.

Comment: @greenapps the ip is fake, too as is the subfolder. What you suggest still gives me a timeout. I don't understand, why this IP is even appearing there.

Comment: If all is fake i cannot help you. Sorry. But `http://91.102.115.250` is not fake. It works. So that is not your site?

Comment: @greenapps sorry, i don't feel comfortable revealing my company's information here.. thanks for trying thou.. :)

Comment: Why aren't supplying a file nam in the url if you want to retrieve a doc?

Comment: "Log.wtf" hahaha